# How to login with facebook access token on meteor using iOS client

Tags: ios, meteor, meteor-accounts

I currently started using meteors, I used use passport for all my login strategies. But for some reason meteor does not work with passports.

How can I achieve facebook login using an access token on meteor from a iOS client. I have been stuck on this for a very long time and can't find a clean way to do it.

Comment: How does your swift client connect to the Meteor app?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is no support in Meteor for using PassportJS.

The Meteor accounts system includes many OAuth options such as Facebook/Google/Twitter etc. I know you are using to using Passport, but the Meteor Accounts system is fully featured, and well integrated into Meteor.

It should be possible to authenticate using something like Passport, but there will be many moments when it will hurt. So many in fact that I don't think it's worth bothering. Resistance is futile.

There is a thing in Apollo called Passport,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-passport

Which promises to do what you want, but it's early days for that (not even at 1.0.0 yet). So it depends if you are interested in the graphQL/Apollo path, it might be worth pursuing.